Stringapp failed to start in cytoscape

Hello, I encountered a problem of stringapp failed to start. I already reinstall string app 3x but still unable to use string app for creating network of genes.
Thank you
Vania

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Looks like you are running a very old version of Cytoscape.  My first suggestion would be to upgrade to the latest release.
